# How do I manually calculate Efferent Coupling (Ce) for a .Net class?

Tags: .net, class-design, metrics, code-metrics

If I want to manually calculate the efferent coupling of a .Net class should I include types from the CLR in my calculation, or just types I have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool NDepend that calculates the efferent coupling takes account of third-party types used. ([Documentation here](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#TypeCe)). Here is a [CQLinq code query](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CQLinq_Syntax.aspx) that shows this fact:

[image: NDepend efferent coupling]

Notice that it is possible to recalculate the efferent coupling only for application types used if you wish.

[image: NDepend efferent coupling without third-party]

If your goal is to detect if a type has too many responsibilities (which is often the case when a type is using many others types, *many* means like several dozens) this makes sense to include types from the .NET Fx. For example the usage of types in `System.IO` or `System.Threading` clearly indicates a special responsibility for the user type. This is also why for detecting many responsibilities, you could count also the number of namespaces used (including third-party ones)

[image: NDepend efferent coupling, parent namespaces]

*Disclaimer: I am working in the NDepend team*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Patrick. NDepend looks like the way to go!